# How to Remove a specific character from the end of the string in php or regex

Tags: php, regex

I am generating a string dynamically. For example The string looks like this

```
$string = "this-is-a-test-string-for-example-";
```

It can also be like this

```
$string = "this-is-a-test-string-for-example";
```

I want if there is a hyphen `"-"` at the end of the string, It should be removed. How can I do that in php or regex?

Comment: Quite easily: substitute `-$` with the empty string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://www.php.net/trim - that function gets characters to trim as last parameter

```
trim($string,"-");
```

or as suggested for right side only

```
rtrim($string,"-");
```

Answer (score 2):

If it always at the end (right) of the string this will work

```
$string = rtrim($string,"-");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cleanedString = preg_replace('/^(this-is-a-test-string-for-example)-$/', '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$delete = array('-');

if(in_array($string[(strlen($string)-1)], $delete))
    $string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string)-1);
```

You can add other characters to delete into `$delete` array.